# How to disallow robots from the first 185 pages?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a website that whereby the first 185 pages are sample profiles for demonstration purpose:

```
http://example.com/profile/1
...
http://example.com/profile/185
```

I want to block these pages from Google as they are somewhat similar in content to avoid penalty for being labelled as duplicate content. Is there a better way to do it than listing them out in *robots.txt* like so:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /profile/1
Disallow: /profile/2
Disallow: /profile/3
...
```

Comment: There isn't necessarily a "penalty" for duplicate content, it's just that Google is likely to only return at most 1 page (at its discretion) from the pages that it thinks are duplicate.

Comment: I think any SEO penalty will come from poorly named URL's.

Comment: Depending on your knowledge you could create a PHP script to output a text file with all your disallow rules.

Comment: The file has to be named `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`.

Comment: Google recommends not using the robots.txt file as a way of handling duplicate content, so using the robots meta tag (or x-robots-tag HTTP header) is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not possible** to use robots.txt (as defined by the [original specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)) in your case. A line like `Disallow: /profile/1` will block all URLs whose paths *start* with `/profile/1`. So this applies to the profiles 1, 10-19, 100-185 (as intended), but also to the profiles 186-199, 1000-1999, 10000, … (not intended).

Workaround: Add a character as suffix, for example a `/`. So your profile URLs would look like `profile/1/`, `/profile/2/`, …. Then you could specify `Disallow: /profile/1/` etc.

That said, some robots.txt parsers support additional features which are not included in the original robots.txt specification. As you say you want to block the pages for Google, [Google gives special meaning to the `$` character](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en):

> To specify matching the end of a URL, use `$`

So for Google, you could write `Disallow: /profile/1$`. But other parsers that don’t support this feature will then index your profiles 1-185 as they only look for URL paths literally starting with `/profile/1$`.

So when you don’t want to add a suffix (and list all `Disallow` lines explicitly), or if you don’t want a Google-only solution (without suffix, but still listing `Disallow` lines explicitly), robots.txt is no solution for you.

Instead, you could use:

- on the HTTP level: the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`

  ```
  X-Robots-Tag: noindex
  ```
- on the HTML level: `meta` element with the `robots` name

  ```
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
  ```

Both ways are [supported by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en).

Answer (score 5):

You could put the [robots meta tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) in all of those pages: `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">`

Comment: Why "nofollow"? If all relevant pages have "noindex" you shouldn't prevent crawling of all links on those pages.

Comment: Not exactly what you proposed, I am using `noindex` on HTTP headers instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a file to be read by a robot, so create it with a robot:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

User-agent: *

<?php
  header("Content-Type:text/plain");
  $limit = 185;

  for($i = 1; $i < $limit ; $i++) 
    echo "Disallow: /profile/$i\n";
 ?>
 # rest of robots.txt here
```

Or if you are using leading zeros (better sorting) replace the echo line with:

```
  printf("Disallow: /profile/%03d\n", $i);
```

Of course, robots.php doesn't work, but that's what mod_rewrite is for:
In .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule robots.txt robots.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am asking and neither is it a better solution than what I have originally.